# How does jdbc truncate numeric values?

Tags: java, jdbc

If I have an SQL column which has a **scale** of `2`. How does `JDBC` handle truncating values which has more than 3 digits after the separator?

**Example:**

insert value `2.989` becomes `2.98` in **Sybase** or `2.99` in **Oracle** depending on the SQL provider.

How does `JDBC` handle that?

Comment: JDBC won't truncate it. The database engine will. And some dbs won't handle it and just throw an exception.

Comment: Please show us your Java code to reproduce the problem (including the `create table` statements). And also tell us what the version of your respective JDBC drivers is (note the number in Oracle's filename is **not** the driver version).

Comment: I agree with @LuiggiMendoza that the truncation will happen in the database and not at the JDBC level.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We have different jdbc drivers, depending on what provider our clients use. For sybase, we use `jconn4, 7.07.21018`

Answer (score -1):

Like @LuiggiMendoza says it depends in the driver, the common solution to this problem, which i think it's much better is to use BigDecimal for fields like money values, with this you can handle the rounding mode and save the number in the exact value you want, keeping your code cross database vendors, yes, it is a little bit slower, but gives you the warranty that the value with you're working in java will be the same when you save it, i mean, i'ts the natural way to handle the decimal values with JPA
In case you want and example:

```
ROUND_CEILING: Ceiling function

             0.333  ->   0.34 
            -0.333  ->  -0.33
ROUND_DOWN: Round towards zero

             0.333  ->   0.33 
            -0.333  ->  -0.33
ROUND_FLOOR: Floor function

             0.333  ->   0.33
            -0.333  ->  -0.34
ROUND_HALF_UP: Round up if decimal >= .5

             0.5  ->  1.0
             0.4  ->  0.0
ROUND_HALF_DOWN: Round up if decimal > .5

             0.5  ->  0.0
             0.6  ->  1.0
```

Example in with BigDecimal:

```
a = new BigDecimal("2.5"); // digit left of 5 is even, so round down
b = new BigDecimal("1.5"); // digit left of 5 is odd, so round up
a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).toString() // => 2
b.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).toString() // => 2
```

Source : [BigDecimal tutorial](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial)

Comment: You're right, but tthere's no evidence here that he isn't already doing that, and it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thats why i commented about using the rounding modes included in the class, i posted it as an answer because that way he would have the security of the saved value reggarding the driver so the question would lost the meaning, but i guess it's not the exact answer since like @LuiggiMendoza already said, it will depends of the database engine, not the driver. With BigDecimal he could take 2.989 and set the behaviour to round like 2.98 or 2.99 in the object itself, have a nice day!